# Python: Make Pyramid With Numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a pyramid with numbers **without reassigning**.

I was able to do this with symbols (see below):

```
def print_pyramid_step_3(heightNum):
    ctr = 1
    while(ctr <= heightNum):
        row_spaces = " " * (heightNum - ctr)
        row = (2*ctr-1) * "$"
        print(row_spaces + row)
        ctr = ctr +1

# Get the input to get the height of the pyramid
heightNum = int(input("Enter the height of the pyramid: "))
print("----"*50)
print("Printing the pyramid by adding spaces to the row")
print("----"*50)
print_pyramid_step_3(heightNum)
```

Output:

```
    $
   $$$
  $$$$$
 $$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$$
```

The desired output Im trying to get looks like this when a user types in a pyramid height of 5 and the starting number is 1.

Desired Output:

```
    1
   234
  56789
 10111213141516
171819202122232425
```

Comment: every number have to use the same number of chars - shorter numbers have to use spaces - ie, `"10"` and `" 5"` should use two chars. If you will have 100 in pyramid then all numbers will have to use three chars - ie. `" 5 "`, `" 10"`, `"100"`

Comment: What do you mean by "without reassigning"?

Comment: You know how many rows you need to draw, so make a for loop for that (not while) and then you can work out for each row how many initial spaces you need to print (height - rownum - 1) (the 1 assumes you start from row index 0). Then print 1 number, the next row print 3, the next 5 and so on, just add 2 to the number printed on each row.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
j = 1
for i in range(height):
    for k in range(1,height + i+1):
        if (k < height - i):
            print(" ", end='')
        else:
            print(j, end='')
            j+=1

    print()
```